# Scala: Map column integer values in a dataframe

Tags: scala, dictionary

I have a mapping from city to country id

```
    cityId, countryId
    1, 1200
    2, 1200
    3, 1200
    4, 3000
    5, 3000
    6, 4000
```

my mapping function looks like

```
    val mapCountry = df.rdd.map(x => (x.getInt(0), 
    x.getInt(1))).collectAsMap()
```

I have a dataframe where I have columns named cityId and countryId. In the dataframe both cityId and countryId contain cityId values
I want to replace the countryId column using a map function.

```
    ft = mapGeography.foldLeft(ft)((acc, ca) => 
    acc.withColumnRenamed(ca._1, ca._2))
```

This is giving me an error that string is expected, but I am passing int. When I run this on columns with string values it works.

Anyone have any idea how this can be adjusted to work with int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, it would be better to join the two dataframes on `cityId` to pick the wanted `countryId`, as shown below.

```
val dfCity = Seq(
  (1, 1200), (2, 1200), (3, 1200), (4, 3000), (5, 3000), (6, 4000)
).toDF("cityId", "countryId")

val dfGeography = Seq(
  (1, 1, 101),  (2, 2, 202), (4, 4, 404), (99, 99, 909)
).toDF("cityId", "countryId", "rank")

val nonIdCols = dfGeography.columns diff Array("cityId", "countryId")

dfGeography.
  join(dfCity, Seq("cityId"), "left_outer").
  select(dfGeography("cityId") +: dfCity("countryId") +: nonIdCols.map(col): _*).
  show
// +------+---------+----+
// |cityId|countryId|rank|
// +------+---------+----+
// |     1|     1200| 101|
// |     2|     1200| 202|
// |     4|     3000| 404|
// |    99|     null| 909|
// +------+---------+----+
```

Note that if `dfCity` is significantly smaller than `dfGeography`, you may consider providing [`SQL query broadcast hint`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/sql-performance-tuning.html#broadcast-hint-for-sql-queries) by simply replacing `dfCity` with `broadcast(dfCity)` within the `join()` expression.